# Compute conditional probability

Tags: probability, decision-theory, decision-trees, decision-problems

I have to solve this problem for a decision analysis network:

> "There is a genetic trait present in 20% of the population that makes
>   that, for men over 65 years, the probability of suffering the type of
>   cancer mentioned in the previous exercise is 15%, while for those who
>   do not have that trait the probability is 2.5%."

In the previous exercise says:

> "The prevalence of a certain type of cancer among men over 65 years of
>   age is 5%."

I have created a decision analysis network with two chance nodes: one from the genetic trait, and another one for the cancer. There is an connect from the genetic node to the cancer node.

I have calculated the probability for the genetic node (I called it G):

$$P(+g)=0.2$$
$$P(\neg g)=0.8$$

But I don't know how to calculate the probability for the cancer node (I called it X). I think its value depends on the genetic trait, so it is a conditional probability, but I don't know how that 5% in *"The prevalence of a certain type of cancer among men over 65 years of age is 5%."* is need it to compute the probability (or maybe I don't need to use it).

How can I compute the probability for node X?

If genetic trait is represented by G variable, and the probability of suffering a cancer is represented by X variable. I need to compute the following probabilities:

$$P(+x|+g)$$
$$P(+x|\neg g)$$
$$P(\neg x|+g)$$
$$P(\neg x|\neg g)$$

Comment: Are you asking why the probability that a man over 65 has probability $5\%$ of contracting this type of cancer?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I need to compute the probability that a man suffer a cancer given a genetic trait.

Comment: You are given that $\Pr(+x \mid +g) = 0.15$ and that $\Pr(+x \mid \neg g) = 0.025$, from which it immediately follows that $\Pr(\neg x \mid +g) = 1 - 0.15 = 0.85$ and $\Pr(\neg x \mid \neg g) = 1 - 0.025 = 0.975$.

Comment: Ok, so I don't need to know that "The prevalence of a certain type of cancer among men over 65 years of age is 5%." from the previous exercise. That is what it is confusing me. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that $\Pr(+x) = \Pr(+g)\Pr(+x \mid +g) + \Pr(\neg g)\Pr(+x \mid \neg g) = (0.2)(0.15) + (0.8)(0.025) = 0.03 + 0.02 = 0.05$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.